measures on tables that don't have time column in dbt with metricflow
I am trying out the dbt semantic model with metric flow. I feel I have a very basic requirement...I have a Threat table, and a device table. I want to join these two and do an aggregation on two columns, one from each table.
Threat table:
createddate, deviceid, eventid
11-01-24 00:00:01, 1, 1

Device table:
deviceid,devicemodel,deviceostype,deviceversion,deviceowner,deviceplatform
1,Model X,iOS,14.4,John Doe,Mobile

My goal is to get this:
Select count(distinct(eventId)) num_threats, count(distinct(deviceid)) num_devices from threat inner join device on threat.deviceid = device.deviceid;

My semantic model:
semantic_models:
 - name: threat
   description: "Threat dimension table"
   defaults:
     agg_time_dimension: detected_date
   model: ref('threat')
   entities:
     - name: threat_event
       type: primary
       expr: eventid
     - name: block_rule
       type: foreign
       expr: blockpolicyrule_id
     - name: device
       type: foreign
       expr: deviceid
   measures:
     - name: threat_count
       expr: eventid
       agg: count
   dimensions:
     - name: threat_category
       type: categorical
       expr: malwarecategory_value
     - name: detected_date
       expr: createddate
       type: time
       type_params:
         time_granularity: day
 - name: device
   model: ref('device')
   description: "Devices"
   entities:
     - name: device
       type: primary
       expr: deviceid
   dimensions:
     - name: os
       type: categorical
       expr: deviceostype
     - name: platform
       type: categorical
       expr: deviceplatform
    measures:
      - name: device_count
        expr: deviceid
        agg: count
metrics:
 - name: threat_total
   description: Number of threat events seen
   type: simple
   label: Threats Total
   type_params:
     measure: threat_count
 - name: device_count
   description: Number of devices seen
   type: simple
   label: Device Count
   type_params:
     measure: device_count

But when I run dbt run I get:
An error occurred while checking aggregation time dimension for a semantic model - AssertionError: Aggregation time dimension for measure device_count is not set! This should either be set directly on the measure specification in the model, or else defaulted to the primary time dimension in the data source containing the measure.
The problem with this error is no date column exists on the device table. It exists on the threat table. It should be fine, though.
